# Необходимо найти индекс второго вхождения второй строки в первую

Tags: javascript

Знаю как найти индекс первого вхождения строки в строку, но как второго не могу вообще понять.

```js
function secondIndex(text, symbol) {

  text = text.split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === symbol) {
      return i
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(secondIndex("find the river", "e"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function secondIndex(text, symbol) {
  var index = text.indexOf(symbol);

  if(index === -1)
    return undefined;
    
  index = text.indexOf(symbol, index + 1);

  if(index !== -1)
    return index;
    
  return undefined;
}
console.log(secondIndex("find the river", "e"));
console.log(secondIndex("find the river", "i"));
console.log(secondIndex("find the river", "d"));
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение, может задам тупой вопрос, но можете пожалуйста объяснить принцип действия вот этой строки index = text.indexOf(symbol, index + 1);

Comment: Второй аргумент метода `indexOf` указывает с какой позиции вести поиск. То есть, мы сначала нашли первое вхождение. А второе вхождение ищем со след. позиции после первого вхождения символа.

Answer (score 3):

Для нахождения второго вхождения, нужно найти первое, и искать второе начиная с найденного.

Для этого можно воспользоваться методом [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), который вторым параметром принимает индекс с которого надо начинать искать.

```js
console.log("find the river".indexOf("e", "find the river".indexOf("e") + 1))
```

Альтернативным решением может стать счетчик или флаг, показывающий какое вхождение найдено:

```js
function secondIndex(text, symbol) {

  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === symbol && ++counter == 2) {
      return i
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(secondIndex("find the river", "e"));

function secondIndex2(text, symbol) {

  var isSecond = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if (text[i] === symbol) {
      if (isSecond) return i;
      isSecond = true;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(secondIndex2("find the river", "e"));
```